# Selenium python proxy code not working as per documentation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox, proxy

I am using below code mentioned in selenium documentation for using proxy in webdriver. but still setting are not working, my real ip is displayed in https://whatismyipaddress.com/

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
"httpProxy": PROXY,
"ftpProxy": PROXY,
"sslProxy": PROXY,
"proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

I am using below code mentioned in selenium documentation for using proxy in webdriver. but still setting are not working, my real ip is displayed in https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: How do you check the ip exactly? Remember only the browser in the code will use that proxy - yet your code doesn't show you grabbing your ip from that browser

Comment: You cannot use Selenium to spoof your real IP address when web scraping if that is what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Every time when I tried using selenium with a proxy I did get any issues.
So, as result, I started using seleniumwire and GeckoDriverManager

```
pip install selenium-wire
pip install webdriver-manager
```

How to use it? Here is a simple example

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

proxy = {
    'http': f'http://{PROXY_LOGIN}:{PROXY_PASSWORD}@{PROXY_HOST}:{PROXY_PORT}',
    'verify_ssl': False
}


options = Options()
service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    seleniumwire_options=proxy,
    service=service,
    options=options
)
```

It works for me greatly.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I copied same code and tried but this code is not working

Comment: @shivaashrith And what kind of problem do you have?

Comment: proxy = {
    'http': '103.152.118.153:8080',
    'verify_ssl': False
}


options = Options()
service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    seleniumwire_options=proxy,
    service=service,
    options=options
)
browser.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/') 

I used same code with proxy but it is displaying my ip address

Comment: @shivaashrith Is your proxy have auth?

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy_ip + ":" + proxy_port))
```

add this arugment for mi working